# Why there is no output?

Tags: java, jsf-2, jstl

If I remove `<c:if>` tag it will display all items from `findByClass`.
How to use `<c:if>` or is there some other way to display `eventId`

```
   <ui:repeat value="#{eventsController.findByClass}" var="item">
                            <c:if test="${item.eventId==10}">
                                <h:outputText value="${item.eventName}"></h:outputText>
                                <p></p>
                        </c:if>
                        </ui:repeat>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead

```
<ui:repeat value="#{eventsController.findByClass}" var="item">
    <h:outputText value="#{item.eventName}" rendered="#{item.eventId==10}"/>
</ui:repeat>
```

Facelets (`ui:repeat`) and JSTL (`c:if`) are evaluated in different phases, which causes the condition in `c:if` to always return false.

Comment: thanks! It works!!! (p.s. I cant give you vote up, because I don't have enough reputation